# Alphabet classification Using Pythton

Tags: python, computer-vision

I am a beginner to image processing. I am trying to detect `A, E, M`  Using `computer vision`.
**How can I detect & classify this image without deep learning**.
The images are

[image: A] [image: E] [image: M]

But have no idea how to do. Any implementation idea or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the [SURF](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html) algorithm. No deep learning required.

Answer (score 0):

just use OpenCV Template matching